# JavaScript For loop appending 4 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript program that isn't properly functioning. For some reasons before it appends what it is actually getting from the checked radio box it appends three times with noting in the append except the styling. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
$(document).delegate('#add-owner', 'pageinit', function () {
            loadOwners();
            $('#add-owner-save').bind('click', function () {
                var permission = $('#editing-permissions option:selected').text();
                var selection = $("input[type='radio']:checked") || [];
                if (selection.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
                        console.log($('#label-' + selection[i].id).find('.owner-name').text());
                        console.log($("input[type='radio']:checked").val());
                        $('.display-owners').append('<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a">' + $('#label-' + selection[i].id).find('.owner-name').text() + '</div><div class="ui-block-b" style="text-align:right">' + permission + '</div></div>');
                    }
                    $('.display-owners').trigger('create');
                }
                $('.display-owners').show();
                $('#add-owner').dialog('close');
                $('input[name=contribute-radio]').attr('checked', false).checkboxradio("refresh");
                return false;
            });
        });
```

I think the problem is that I have multiple radio areas on this page. How do I specify that I just want these radio buttons are the ones I want it to checked?

Comment: What value does `selection.length` have? What are you getting in the cnosole?

Comment: It returns 4 every time in the console. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Would you please put up a jsfiddle which contains the relevant HTML as well? That might be a big help in assisting to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since said you have multiple sets of radio buttons, the selector you're using is finding all of them on the page so that is why you have multiple "checked" radio buttons.

This:

```
var selection = $("input[type='radio']:checked") || [];
```

To this:

```
var selection = $("input[name='radioset1']:checked") || [];
```

Then just name each radio set different and replace "radioset1" with the set you need for this one.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

<strike>... + $('#label-' + selection[i].id).find('...</strike>

should be like this:

```
... + $('#label-' + selection[i].attr('id')).find('...
```

because what you have in `selection` array are jQuery objects, not DOM elements objects.

Thanks **Esalija** for pointing out my assumption was not correct.

Comment: `selection` is not an array but a jQuery object... `var selection = $("input[type='radio']:checked") || [];` the `|| []` is never executed because objects are always truthy

Comment: It still went through 4 times. Only it through an error message all 4 times and crashed the program.